# Compute a quantum state $\rho$ corresponding to an ensemble

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computation, quantum-information

I am trying to solve the following problem

Consider the ensemble consisting of the qubit states $|0⟩⟨0|$ and $|1⟩⟨1|$ occuring with probabilities 2/3 and 1/3, respectively.
Compute the quantum state $\rho$ corresponding to this ensemble. Is $ρ $ pure or mixed?

My try:

I think there is nothing to compute. The  quantum state is
$\rho=\frac{2}{3}|0⟩⟨0|+\frac{1}{3}|1⟩⟨1|=
\pmatrix{2/3 & 0 \\ 0 & 1/3} $.
...,is there?  **Is this how the quatum state is always computed given an ensamble?**

To see if it is pure:
If it where pure there would exist
a unit vector $|\psi⟩=(a,b)^T$ such that
$\rho=|\psi⟩⟨\psi|=\pmatrix{a^2 & ab \\ ab & b^2}$, so $a^2=2/3$, $b^2=1/3$,$ab=0$ where a,b are complex numbers. The system is incompatible because $a=0 $ or $b=0$ contradicts that$a^2=2/3$ and $b^2=1/3$. Therefore since such $|\psi⟩$ does not exist, the state is mixed

**Any feedback would be appreciated. Is this correct? Is there something wrong?**

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Yep correct. Also consider the following (easy to show). A state is pure if and only if $\mathrm{tr} (\rho^2) =1$.